# How to sort data by type in React JS API fetched data

Tags: reactjs, sorting, next.js, mern

this is related to advertising website developed using MERN stack.

I want to sort data by ad type "reach-up-ad" and display all the other ads underneath of this ad type. Fetching data through the axios and then map, sort or filter according to the need.

example :

- reach-up-ad
- unpaid ad
- unpaid ad
- unpaid ad
  .......

paid ad should always display on the top of the list.

How can I implement this feature on my Nextjs code?

Code:

```
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await getPosts();
        const filterData = await data?.filter(obj => obj.adPromote == "free-ad" || obj.adPromote == "reach-up-ad")
        .map(obj => {
            return {
                ...obj,
                adImg: obj.photos[0] || 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/dbdbdb/dbdbdb',
                title: `${obj.title} (${obj.features.condition})`,
                location: `Posted On ${new Date(obj.createdAt).toDateString()}, ${obj.location.district}, ${obj.location.location} `,
                price: obj.price,
                cardTag: 'toItem',
                totalTime: timeSince(obj.createdAt),
                district: obj.location.district
            }
        });

        setNoOfPages(Math.ceil(filterData?.length / itemsPerPage))
        setPosts(filterData)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do using below code, you just need to sort based on your type.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the data from your backend API
    axios.get('/api/ads')
      .then(response => {
        // Sort the data by ad type
        const sortedAds = response.data.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.type === 'paid ad' && b.type !== 'paid ad') {
            return -1;
          } else if (a.type !== 'paid ad' && b.type === 'paid ad') {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });

        setAds(sortedAds);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching ads:', error);
      });
  }, []);
```